# Virtual unix command-line environment on the iPad

Tags: command-line, virtual-machine, c, iphone

Is there a lightweight virtualized Linux or other unix environment that I can run on the iPad? Like VirtualBox for iPad. I only really need a minimal system — something along the lines of [Microcore Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/welcome.html), so no X server or anything like that. Just a console with a reasonable C compiler; if gcc is not available, tcc (Tiny C Compiler) or something like it would be fine.

I'd really like it to be virtualized so that I don't inadvertently mess up my iPad by playing with the linuxbox inside.

Comment: Do you insist on a *Linux* environment, or is any unix environment ok? The iPad does run on iOS, which is a modified version of OSX, and you can get a command line on it if it's jailbroken (if your device isn't jailbroken, forget it). I don't know how much virtualization there is; as long as you use a separate, non-root user you'll be fine.

Comment: @Gilles Actually a Unix environment would be ok. However, I am reluctant to jailbreak my iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think this should be feasible, it is very unlikely even on a jailbroken iPad, and extremely unlikely on a non-jailbroken device.

Get a Linux VPS or a system to which you can SSH to, and install iSSH on your iPad, it's as closest as you can get to Linux-on-iPad.